# SQLite Check Duplicate Records

Tags: android, sqlite, duplicates

```
    public class LocalCached extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        public boolean insertNewDataSet(ArrayList<Obstacle> newObs) {

        if (newObs.size() > 0) {
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            getRowsCount();
            switch (checkFlag) {
            case NO_RECORDS:

//              this.onCreate(db);
//              for (int i = 0; i < newObs.size(); i++) {
//                  insertNewObstacle(newObs.get(i));
//              }
//              break;
            case THERE_IS_RECORDS:
                checkDublicate(newObs.get(0), newObs.get(newObs.size() - 1));
                break;
            case DATA_MATCHED:
                if (MatabbatManager.DEBUG)
                    Log.i(MatabbatManager.TAG, "Data Already Exist");
                break;
            case DATA_NOT_MATCHED:
                // db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                for (int i = 0; i < newObs.size(); i++) {
                    insertNewObstacle(newObs.get(i));
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            db.close();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void getRowsCount() {
        dblocs = this.getReadableDatabase();
        dblocs.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + OBSTACLES_TABLE, new String[] {});
        if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
            checkFlag = THERE_IS_RECORDS;
        } else {
            checkFlag = NO_RECORDS;
        }
        cur.close();
        dblocs.close();
    }

    public void checkDublicate(Obstacle firstObstacle, Obstacle lastObstacle) {
        dblocs = this.getReadableDatabase();
        dblocs.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + OBSTACLES_TABLE, new String[] {});
        cur.moveToFirst();
        if (cur.getDouble(0) == firstObstacle.getLongitude()
                && cur.getDouble(1) == firstObstacle.getLatitude()) {
            cur.moveToLast();
            if (cur.getDouble(0) == lastObstacle.getLongitude()
                    && cur.getDouble(1) == lastObstacle.getLatitude()) {
                checkFlag = DATA_MATCHED;
            }
        } else {

            checkFlag = DATA_NOT_MATCHED;

        }

        cur.close();
        dblocs.close();
    }

    public void insertNewObstacle(Obstacle newObstacle) {

//       db = this.getWritableDatabase();
//          
        db.execSQL("Insert into " + OBSTACLES_TABLE + " Values ( ' "
                + newObstacle.getLongitude() + "' , ' "
                + newObstacle.getLatitude() + "' , ' "
                + newObstacle.getDirection() + "' , ' " + newObstacle.getType()
                + "' , ' " + newObstacle.getAddress() + "' , '"
                + newObstacle.getSubmissionTime() + "' , '"
                + newObstacle.getSubmitterName() + "' )");
              db.close();
    }
```

The question is how to get read and write database or it's not possible ?

The error says that to close the connection before opening new one that's happen when i'm trying to check duplicate records(it's an array of data so i'm checking the first and the last record only).

Update:

The Exception:

```
A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.nilecode.matabat/databases/localobstaclesdb' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is how to get read and write database or it's not possible ?

You can also do reads on the database returned by `getWritableDatabase()`. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29):

> Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

As you didnt post full/compileable code i can only guess. But this should be working just fine.

```
public class LocalCached extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    SqlDataBase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); //Method 1
    Cursor cursor = cursor.rawQuery("",null);
    // check duplicate
    cursor.close(); 
    db.close();

    db = this.getWritableeDatabase();  //Method 2
    // do whatever
    db.close();
}
```

You can do the check in a seperate Method, but you have to make sure that Method 1 is called before Method 2 calls getWriteableDatabase.

And if you are doing your db work in background, which seems like the smartest thing to do, since you dont want you app to hang, you might want to make your Methods synchronized to avoid  multithread issues.

Comment: Thanks man that was helpful but synchronized  methods always throws an exception so i give it up or i need to unlock before accessing it?

Comment: can you add the exception?

Comment: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(11141): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.nilecode.matabat/databases/localobstaclesdb' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Comment: well it seems you are not releasing a reference to your db in some method. you would have to post your whole databse logic

Comment: i'm closing at the end of every method.

Comment: as i said, id need the whole db to figure this out.

Comment: dblocs.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + OBSTACLES_TABLE, new String[] {});
        if (cur.getCount() != 0) {

Comment: the error was at this line 

dblocs.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + OBSTACLES_TABLE, new String[] 

{});

it should be :

cur=dblocs.rawQuery();

thx man